# Alter command is taking long time, but not executing in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

The below ALTER command is taking long time, but not executing.

```
alter table DETAILS alter column row_id type numeric(20);
```

DDL is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Details
(
  row_id numeric(15,0) NOT NULL,
  intfid character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  seqno numeric(15,0) NOT NULL,
  record_id numeric(15,0) NOT NULL,  
  lstmoddate timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  rcvddate timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT current_date,
  record_type character varying(60),
  xmldata bytea,
  CONSTRAINT mrd_pk PRIMARY KEY (rcvddate, intfid, seqno, record_id)
)
```

Comment: what is the data size there in the table?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo : There are already 280 rows present in the Details table.

Comment: Most probably you have transactions that are using the table and your `alter table` is waiting for the lock. Check `pg_stat_activity` to see if your statement is waiting.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/84739/1822

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : After running, select * from pg_stat_activity , alter statement is active. But not executing.

Comment: What does the column `waiting` say?

Comment: Thanks to everyone. After restarting postgresql enterprise admin server, the problem is resolved.  I can able to execute alter statement. I think the problem is due to the more number of activities running on the server, out of those activities, more number of activities are active, but not returning any result. Once you restart the server, all active activities locks will be cleared. So only idle activities will remain in the server.

Comment: But did you find the culprit? The query that was locking all other activity? Restarting a server isn't a real solution, just a quick fix until the problem happens again.